# Blur Video When Shared on whatsapp status objective c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In my Application I need to put Image on the video. The Size of Image and video are same.
Video size is fix = 1080 x 1080
Image Size is fix = 1080 x 1080

My problem is blur video when i share on whatsapp status.
I have check other applications also but it not too much low compress. But in my case it too much lower quality.

I am Export video in AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality.

Please suggest me any github link which is add image on video.

URL path :

```
NSURL *filepath = [NSURL URLWithString:self.video_url];
```

Mix Composition :

```
AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:filepath options:nil];
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo  preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVAssetTrack *clipVideoTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVAssetTrack *clipAudioTrack = [[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0];
//If you need audio as well add the Asset Track for audio here

CGSize firstvideoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize;
CGSize videoSize = clipVideoTrack.naturalSize;
UIInterfaceOrientation mode = [self checkVideoTrack:videoAsset];
    
  if (mode == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
  {
      if(firstvideoSize.height<=firstvideoSize.width)
      {
          videoSize.height=firstvideoSize.width;
          videoSize.width=firstvideoSize.height;
      }
      
  }
  else if(mode == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
  {
    if(firstvideoSize.height>=firstvideoSize.width)
    {
        videoSize.height=firstvideoSize.width;
        videoSize.width=firstvideoSize.height;
    }
  }

[compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipVideoTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];
[compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, videoAsset.duration) ofTrack:clipAudioTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

[compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:[[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] preferredTransform]];
```

Create Image Layer :

```
UIImage *myImage = image;
CALayer *aLayer = [CALayer layer];
aLayer.contents = (id)myImage.CGImage;
aLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, image.size.width, image.size.height); //Needed for proper display. We are using the app icon (57x57). If you use 0,0 you will not see it
aLayer.contentsGravity=kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
aLayer.opacity = 1.0; //Feel free to alter the alpha here

CALayer *parentLayer = [CALayer layer];
CALayer *videoLayer = [CALayer layer];
parentLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
videoLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, videoSize.width, videoSize.height);
[parentLayer addSublayer:videoLayer];
[parentLayer addSublayer:aLayer];
    
AVMutableVideoComposition* videoComp = [AVMutableVideoComposition videoComposition];
videoComp.renderSize = videoSize;
videoComp.frameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 30);
videoComp.animationTool = [AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool videoCompositionCoreAnimationToolWithPostProcessingAsVideoLayer:videoLayer inLayer:parentLayer];
```

instruction

```
AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction *instruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction videoCompositionInstruction];

instruction.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, [mixComposition duration]);

AVAssetTrack *videoTrack = [[mixComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0];

AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction* layerInstruction = [AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction videoCompositionLayerInstructionWithAssetTrack:videoTrack];

 instruction.layerInstructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:layerInstruction];

 videoComp.instructions = [NSArray arrayWithObject: instruction];
    
 AVAssetExportSession *_assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality];
    _assetExport.videoComposition = videoComp;
NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];

NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Videos"];
// New Folder is your folder name
NSError *error = nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

NSString *saveFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Videos/%@",[self generateFileNameWithExtension:@".mp4"]];
NSURL *exportUrl =  [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:saveFilePath];


if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportUrl.path])
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportUrl.path error:nil];
}

_assetExport.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4;
_assetExport.outputURL = exportUrl;


[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:
 ^(void ) {

    switch (_assetExport.status)
    {
            
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown:
            NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusUnknown");
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting:
            NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusWaiting");
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting:
            NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusExporting");
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted:
            NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted");
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed:
            NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed");
            break;
        case AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled:
            NSLog(@"AVAssetExportSessionStatusCancelled");
            break;
    }
    
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self saveVideoWithURL:exportUrl];
    });
}];
```

Save Video With URL :

```
- (void)saveVideoWithURL:(NSURL *)filePath {

    [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:filePath completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
        
        if(assetURL) {

        
        [self.navigationController.view makeToast:@"Save video successfully in gallery"
                                         duration:1.0
                                         position:CSToastPositionBottom];

    } else {
        
        UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController
                                     alertControllerWithTitle:@"Error"
                                     message:@"something went wrong"
                                     preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        
        UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
                                    actionWithTitle:@"Ok"
                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                    {
                                        
                                    }];
        
        [alert addAction:yesButton];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}];
```

}